# Error reading data from the old files, writing it into the new files and then deleting the old files in Python

Tags: python, file, move

I'm trying to use below code to read 5 files from source, write them in destination and then deleting the files in source. I get the following error: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\data\\AM\\Desktop\\tester1`. The file by the way look like this: [image]

```
import os
import time

source = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\tester'
destination = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\tester1'


for file in os.listdir(source):
    file_path = os.path.join(source, file)
    if not os.path.isfile:
        continue
    print(file_path)


with open (file_path, 'r') as IN, open (destination, 'w') as OUT:
    data ={
            'Power': None,
            }
    for line in IN:
        splitter = (ID, Item, Content, Status) = line.strip().split()
        if Item in data == "Power":
            Content = str(int(Content) * 10)

os.remove(IN)
```

Comment: This is an error from the OS. You do not have the permission to create that file.

Comment: What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-written your entire code. I assume you want to update the value of `Power` by a multiple of 10 and write the updated content into a new file. The below code will do just that.

Your code had multiple issues, first and foremost, most of what you wanted in your head did not get written in the code (like writing into a new file, providing what and where to write, etc.). The original issue of the permission was because you were trying to open a `directory` to write instead of a `file`.

```
source = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\tester'
destination = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\tester1' 

for file in os.listdir(source):
    source_file = os.path.join(source, file)
    destination_file=os.path.join(destination, file)
    if not os.path.isfile:
        continue
    print(source_file)

    with open (source_file, 'r') as IN , open (destination_file, 'w') as OUT: 
        data={
            'Power': None,
        }
        for line in IN:
            splitter = (ID, Item, Content, Status) = line.strip().split()
            if Item in data:# == "Power": #Changed
                Content = str(int(Content) * 10)
                OUT.write(ID+'\t'+Item+'\t'+Content+'\t'+Status+'\n') #Added to write the content into destination file.
            else:
                OUT.write(line) #Added to write the content into destination file.

    os.remove(source_file)
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Already tried using file_path instead of In. I get the same error  `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\data\\AM\\Desktop\\tester1'` And how would you rewrite the code to make it do what I want?

Comment: Thank you first. Well the move from source to destination took place, however all my files got deleted and I received 1 empty file in destination named sestinationFileName. So the files did not even got modified...

Comment: @AK28: Check now.

Comment: This did exactly where I was looking for. Just 2 questions if you mind. I noticed that if I removed splitter is actually the most important piece of code, what does it exaclty do?

Comment: I assume you want to understand what `splitter = (ID, Item, Content, Status) = line.strip().split()` does. The strip() method returns a copy of the string by removing both the leading and the trailing characters passed as parameter. And split() separates the characters by the parameter passed into different variables, in this case `(ID, Item, Content, Status)`. `splitter` just stores all of them as an array. I just reused what you wrote, I would have stopped at `(ID, Item, Content, Status)` extraction. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, so you are saying that it is not necessary to use the line.strip().split() method? If see see any chances to make the code slimmer/smoother I would be very interesting to know how...

Comment: No, I meant you can remove the `splitter=` part. Keep experimenting with the code.. you will learn new ways of doing things.. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're going for here, but here's what I could come up with the question put into the title.

```
import os

# Takes the text from the old file
with open('old file path.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

# Takes text from old file and writes it to the new file
with open('new file path.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)

# Removes the old text file
os.remove('old file path.txt')
```

Comment: This will only work for 1 specific file. I have 5 files and I need to modify them (content of Power * 10) before pasting them in destination.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds from your description like this line fails:

```
with open (file_path, 'r') as IN, open (destination, 'w') as OUT:
```

Because of this operation:

```
open (destination, 'w')
```

So, you might not have write-access to

```
c:\data\AM\Desktop\tester1
```

Set file permission on Windows systems:
https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/

Comment: Yes, that is how far I've come but the question is Why I don't have write-access in something which I created by myself?

Comment: The answer can be found within your systems Access Control Lists, search for your user profile, and see which rights are attributed to it.(To change permissions, click on "edit", see guide link above)

Comment: Well I already have most of the rights, including writing, reading etc. I think the fault has to do something with the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Sherin Jayanand

One more question bro, I wanted to try something out with some pieces of your code. I made this of it:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

#Make source, destination and archive paths.
source = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Source'
destination = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Destination'
archive = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Archive'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for f in files:
        pads = (root + '\\' + f)
#        print(pads)
    for file in os.listdir(source):
        dst_path=os.path.join(destination, file)
        print(dst_path)

    with open(pads, 'r') as IN, open(dst_path, 'w') as OUT:
        data={'Power': None,
              }
        for line in IN:
            (ID, Item, Content, Status) = line.strip().split()
            if Item in data:
                Content = str(int(Content) * 10)
                OUT.write(ID+'\t'+Item+'\t'+Content+'\t'+Status+'\n')
            else:
                OUT.write(line)
```

But again I received the same error: `Permission denied: 'c:\\data\\AM\\Desktop\\Destination\\C'`

How comes? Thank you very much!